# write in a vector<string> with for loop

Tags: c++

I want to do something like this but how can i do it without push_back?
current_state, next_states, outputs have different values for each line

```
std::vector<string> example;

for(i=0; i<7; i++)
{
  std::string current_state = "a";
  std::string next_states = "abcd";
  std::string outputs = "10x1";
  example.push_back("STATE \s", current_state, " TO \s", next_states, " OUT ", outputs, " \n ");
}
```

I am trying to have this output

```
STATE a TO abcd OUT 10x1
STATE b TO aabd OUT 11x1
STATE c TO aaac OUT 1001
```

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate `std::string` objects using the normal `+` operator, like e.g.

```
example.push_back("STATE " + current_state + " TO " + next_states + " OUT " + outputs + " \n ");
```